# How to avoid printing path if consecutive returns are hit?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

Before

```
host /workplace/sudo/myapp
>
host /workplace/sudo/myapp
>
host /workplace/sudo/myapp
>
host /workplace/sudo/myapp
>
host /workplace/sudo/myapp
>
```

Expecting:

```
>
>
>
>
host /workplace/sudo/myapp
>
```

What exact config do I need in Zsh to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.zshrc` file:

```sh
PS1='%m %~
> '
autoload -Uz add-zle-hook-widget
add-zle-hook-widget line-finish remove-pwd
remove-pwd() {
  PS1='> ' zle .reset-prompt
  zle -R
}
```